# algorithm to return the paths from one vertex to all others in a tree graph

Tags: matlab, tree, traversal, depth-first-search

If i have a tree that is a minimum spanning tree on a graph G, and I want to compute the paths from one vertex to all other vertices on the tree, what is the best way of doing so?

I am thinking that it is possibly best to use a stack data structure to store the paths, and use DFS recursively - adding each new vertex to the stack and once there is no more unvisited nodes, storing that stack as a path, and continuing.. or, in pseudocode:

```
P = {}
stack = []
visited = []
dfs(root_node, stack, visited, P)

def dfs(curr_node, stack visited, P):
    push curr_node to stack
    for all n connected to curr_node
        if n not in visited
            dfs(n, stack visited, P)
    add current stack to P
    pop curr_node from stack
    mark curr_node as visited
```

would this work? is there a better way that people can suggest i do this?

also, is there any considerations that i should take into account if i wanted to implement this in matlab? i know there is no stack data structure in matlab, but i figure i could just use a vector like this:

```
% push
stack = [stack, val];
% or
stack(end+1) = val;

% pop
stack(end) = [];
```

is that okay to use? and which version of push would be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm would work if you mark your node visited *before* diving into the adjacent graph nodes. Otherwise your DFS will bounce between the root node and the first in the adjacency list forever. Of course, that won't happen if your graph is directed.

The `push` and `pop` by growing and shrinking a vector works well in MATLAB for small stack. But if you have many nodes, you'd better implement it the classic way. i.e.  pre-allocate the arrays, declare a stack pointer, and manipulate that:

```
N = size(adjacency_matrix, 1); the number of nodes

% create
stack = zeros(N,1);
sptr  = 0;

% push
sptr = sptr + 1;
stack(sptr) = val;

% pop
if sptr > 0
        sptr = sptr - 1;
end;
```

Otherwise you'd end up with fragmented memory and quadratic execution times on pushing new elements (which is supposed to be O(1)).

Comment: thanks for that, i implemented my method and it worked fine for a small graph, but it took ages for one with 500 vertices.. i will implement it the way you suggested and see if that speeds things up..

Comment: Just one quick follow-up question: if it is an undirected graph, then i know that my matrix is always going to be symmetrical, if i wanted to find all pairs of paths by iterating this algorithm over all vertices, is there a way of exploiting this symmetry so that it doesnt have to find a path from i->j AND j->i?

Comment: @guskenny83 I guess that you'll have to call DFS from node `i` only on adjacent nodes `j` that have `j > i`. But you need to test it.